# How does rospy.Timer behave if it triggers while the previous callback is still busy?

Tags: ros, rospy, callback, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a `rospy.Timer` (periodic, not one-shot) to handle a long-running process in a non-blocking way. I only want one instance of the process to be running at any one time. Therefore, I thought I would have to implement some sort of lock in order to prevent subsequent Timer callbacks from triggering new instances of the process.

However, it seems like I didn't have to! Subsequent callbacks are not called if the previous one is still working. Or are they added to a queue like subscriber callbacks? Either is a good thing in my use case, but where can I find out more about it? It's not mentioned in http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Timer from what I can tell.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250750/how-does-rospy.timer-behave-if-it-triggers-while-the-previous-callback-is-still-busy?/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-12-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could have a look at the code:
[timer.py](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/timer.py)

The callback is directly executed (no thread) so if your function takes longer than your rate, it will be called as fast as possible (independent of your specified rate).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-12-26**:
Thanks for the link! According to the source code, it looks like the callback should be getting called regardless of whether the previous one has returned. That's not what I observed though. Hmm. I'll take another look.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-12-26**:
Why do you think so? The callback is called in line 223 in the main loop. So the execution waits there until your function finished.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-12-26**:
Oh, now I get it! **The entire Timer / thread is getting blocked** by the call to the long-running callback. Thanks again @NEngelhard :-)